# Load Objects Into a ListView in Android (C#)

Tags: c#, android, listview

I'm looking to use a `ListView` in Android to display details of customers, for example Firstname, Surname, Address etc...

I have an object declared that looks like;

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Netname { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
}
```

I've been looking for examples ([Xamarin example](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data/)) of how to bind a collection in C#/Android to a `ListView` that users are able to click on to see further detaisl regarding that `Customer` however so far I have had no luck.

In my C# application I've used `ObservableCollection` and `DataGrid`, but I am struggling to find a workable equivalent in Android (I'm completely new to android).

Is there an equivalent that I can use in my Android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an adapter that extends `BaseAdapter` to hold the data and returns each row using the `getView` method in which you bind each value of your list to a View in your screen. Example from [Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview's_appearance/#Referencing_a_Custom_Row_View):

```
listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List); // get reference to the ListView in the layout
// populate the listview with data
listView.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, tableItems);
listView.ItemClick += OnListItemClick;  // to be defined
```

Adapter class:

```
public class HomeScreenAdapter : BaseAdapter<TableItem> 
{
   List<TableItem> items;
   Activity context;
   public HomeScreenAdapter(Activity context, List<TableItem> items)
       : base()
   {
       this.context = context;
       this.items = items;
   }
   public override long GetItemId(int position)
   {
       return position;
   }
   public override TableItem this[int position]
   {
       get { return items[position]; }
   }
   public override int Count
   {
       get { return items.Count; }
   }
   public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {
       var item = items[position];
       View view = convertView;
       if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
           view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomView, null);
       view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.Heading;
       view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.SubHeading;
       view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Image).SetImageResource(item.ImageResourceId);
       return view;
   }
}
```

For performance enhancements, take a look at [ViewHolder](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Comment: I've tagged `C#` in my question - do you have an example for C# instead of `Java`?

Comment: @CBreeze updated with c# example. It is the same but with C# syntax.

Comment: I really appreciate that thanks. The only part I can't get my head round is the `Layout.CustomView`. Do I have to create an xml file that simulates one row?

Comment: @CBreeze Unless you want to display just one line of text in each row, then yes you need to create an XML as a template for one row.

Comment: OK just one last question, in your example where there is `CustomView` - I assume that is the row template. I have created an XML file as a template for the row (job_row) and done this - `view = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.job_row, null);` however it simply says Resource.Layout does not contain it. How can I link the XML file in as the new row?

Comment: @CBreeze you added the XML to  `/Resources/Layout/` right ?

Comment: @CBreeze I think you added xml file from the VS Menu. You need to `Add Item` > `Android Layout` for it to work (to be added to the Resource Designer).